# subplot in R plotly with bar diagram

Tags: r, graph, plotly

I have problem reproducing a ggplot diagram with plotly. I have evolutions decomposed in 5 components (effet) for a bunch of sectors (A17). I would like to get a bar diagram for each sector, that put all the evolution of the sector side by side.  Here's a subset of my data :

```
t <- structure(list(A17 = c("FZ", "GZ", "FZ", "GZ", "FZ", "GZ", "FZ", 
"GZ", "FZ", "GZ"), effet = c("effetAugmentation", "effetAugmentation", 
"effetDiminution", "effetDiminution", "effetEntreeA17", "effetEntreeA17", 
"effetSuppression", "effetSuppression", "effetNouveaux", "effetNouveaux"
), value = c(4133.836, 5765.367, -1511.959, -1625.793, 76, 137, 
-88, -247, 606, 748)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("A17", "effet", "value"))
```

And here's what I do with ggplot, which is exactly what I look for :

```
ggplot(t,aes(x=1,y=value,fill=effet)) +geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+facet_wrap(~A17)
```

With plotl_ly, I can make one graph :

```
plot_ly(t,x=~effet,y=~value,type="bar",split=~effet)
```

But If I try to facet, things go wrong. I try this  :

```
t <-t %>% mutate(id = dense_rank(A17))
p <-plot_ly(t,x=~effet, y=~value,type="bar",split=~effet,xaxis=paste0("x",~id))
subplot(p,nrows=3)
```

but the graph I get make no sense.

Any help would be appreciated !

edit : update syntax to plotly 4.5, it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `ggplotly()`?

Comment: I got an interesting error with ggplotly() : it seems to work but the negative bars are now positive... does it appear ok on your computer ?

Comment: Looks like a bug at the moment. See this: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560